# jdbc returns mySQL syntax error exception for a valid query

Tags: mysql, jdbc, syntax-error

I user the java.sql.Statement.excecuteUpdate method to create a table and insert some values into the database through JDBC. However, it gives me MySQL syntax exceptions for no reason. I copied and pasted the same code into command prompt. it worked.

I'm wondering why it's doing that??

Comment: Can you provide the query and code you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Guessing**

You cannot do a query like: insert ...; insert ... ; only **one query per method call**

Comment: is there an easy way to do a bunch of insert?